# reference parent table in form without user input

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have two tables: GEO and SHIP.  Inside ship rests a foreignkey to Geo.
I have forms.py showing:

```
class Geo(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Geo
        exclude = []


class Ship(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Ship
        exclude = ['ShipClass', 'Geo']
```

I have a html page showing a list of GEOs, then the use picks a Geo.  A page comes up with specific information about that GEO, and a list of ships (child table/ship).  How do I refer to the Ship form to auto attach the right GEO foreign key without showing it in the form?

Sorry...Noob here. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Override `save()` method in the `ShipForm` and call it from your view with `geo` argument:

```
class ShipForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Ship
        exclude = ['ShipClass', 'Geo']

    def save(self, geo):
        ship = super(ShipForm, self).save(commit=False)
        ship.geo = geo
        ship.save()
        return ship
```

Or you can do the same trick with `commit=False` right in the view :-)

```
if form.is_valid():
    ship = form.save(commit=False)
    ship.geo = geo
    ship.save()
    return redirect(ship)
```

Comment: Absolutely awesome. I used the second side as it was easier for me to grasp.  I appreciate it.